# Convert datetime from a specific timezone into unix timestamp in python

Tags: python

I have data in the following format:

```
{"date":"2020-04-09","minute":"15:59","label":"3:59 PM"}
```

This datetime is in New York Timezone (not local time). How do I convert it into a unix timestamp?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we convert :

```
import time
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(y,m,d,h,m,s,ms)
unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

to change timezone:

```
d = datetime.datetime(y,m,d,h,m,s,ms,timezoneinfo)
```

In your case:

```
import time
import datetime
from dateutil import tz


def convert(y,m,d,h,min,sec,ms):
    NYC = tz.gettz('America/ New_York')
    d = datetime.datetime(y,m,d,h,min,sec,ms,tzinfo = NYC)
    return time.mktime(d.timetuple())
    unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())

print(convert(2020,5,3,3,59,0,0))
```

You can get TZ names from : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: What about the timezone?

Comment: timezone is taken from your machine

Comment: No, the date in the data is not from local time.